# I need code to unblock adding new worksheets in excel vba

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I am writing an add in for excel. It is supposed to create a new worksheet, then copy data from the pre-existing worksheets.

Now the whole add-in works on another excel document. But the one I need it to work in has disabled the ability to add new worksheets.

Can someone please tell me what code enables this?

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Dim WSheet As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set WSheet = Sheets("DispersionList")
On Error Resume Next
Dim works As Worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect

If WSheet Is Nothing Then
Set works = Worksheets.add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "DispersionList"
Call makeFormat

Worksheets(1).Activate
End If

DispersionForm.Enabled = True
DispersionForm.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it protected?  thisworkbook.unprotect("password")

Comment: @pnuts unfortunately i don't know the password, and their vba project is also password protected so i cant see what they did, i am trying to find a workaround>

Comment: this is the code that i use 'Sub Auto_Open()

Dim WSheet As Worksheet

Set WSheet = Sheets("DispersionList")
On Error Resume Next
Dim works As Worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect

If WSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set works = Worksheets.add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "DispersionList"
Call makeFormat

Worksheets(1).Activate
End If

DispersionForm.Enabled = True
DispersionForm.Show

End Sub'      

but now it gives me the following error "run time error'91' object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: @pnuts I added the code to my original post. sorry 'bout the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Like pnuts mentioned above, if you search Google/SO, you will find plenty of posts which talk about hacking the password. However my answer is not about hacking the password but about alternative(s) that you can employ to play around with the workbook. If someone protected the Excel file then it is obvious that you are not meant to fiddle with it :) And as a personal choice, I do not assist with hacking. If you can get the password from the author then there's nothing like it.

There could be 2 kinds of protection that I can think of which will stop you from adding sheets to that workbook.

1. Via Code
2. Workbook Structure is protected.

If you want to play around with the workbook with not the **intention of hacking** it then you have couple of options.

1. If the protection is via code, then that file could be an xls or xlsm file which supports macros. Here what the author might have done is written a code where the moment you add a sheet, it is immediately deleted. In such a case, simply resave the file as an xlsx file. Close the file and re-open it so that you can then add sheets to it and play with it without hacking it.
2. If the workbook structure is protected then there is nothing much you can do except copy (if it allows) the cells from the existing workbook to a new workbook and then play with it

Comment: Thank you, i am not trying to hack the workbook, i am trying to avoid this as far as possible. i just need to process some information on it into another format which the current macro does not support. and the easiest would have been just to create a new worksheet and then copy the info to it.

Comment: this is slightly off topic, but i dont think i need to post a whole new questiion for this. i created a new workbook in the code 
    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = Workbooks.add

but now i want to save the workbook in the same folder of the original file. (using relative path) what code do i use?